# Symfony2 did not create vendor tables

Tags: database, symfony

I have just installed symfony2 and I used this statement

`php app/console doctrine:schema:create`

When I see the database table, there is only one table and that is for my entity.
I can't see any base tables.

Is that normal??

Comment: Base tables? What are them? Symfony creates only the tables from your entities!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely normal. Symfony is a framework, it doesn't need any database tables. All settings for it are saved in configuration files which can be found in `/app/config` directory (application config files). And config files for bundles can be found in `bundle_dir/Resources/config`

Database is for your entities only. Have in  mind that if you use "Doctrine Migrations", it will indeed create one database table called "doctrine_migrations".

Comment: But i can't see that table in database.

Comment: So you don't use doctrine migrations.....I really can't see the problem. If you use it, table will appear.

Answer (score 1):

The framework itself hasn't got any "base tables". It persists your entities only.